# How can I programmatically add a prior state using angular ui router/ionicframework

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm using ionicframework v1.3.0 (which is using angular-ui-router v0.2.13). After successful login, the user sees a landing page. Sometimes I want to have my user jump to a special page after login, but still be able to navigate to the landing page.

Currently, if I just use a `$state.go('/special-page', someParams)`, then the user will not see the link for the back/home button in the ion-nav-bar. However, if the user clicks a button to navigate to the special page from the landing page, they will see the back/home button. How can I accomplish this? I thought it might be possible to splice/inject the '/landing-page' state in the navigation stack to do so.